# Linking libraries to a QT project using pkg-config output

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

This is a bit of a newbie question. I am trying to add the OpenCV libraries to a QT project.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122448/where-does-opencv-install-its-libs-in-ubuntu) says the link flags are given by

```
pkg-config --libs opencv
```

If I paste the command line output into the project file like:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lml -lcvaux -lhighgui -lcv -lcxcore
```

then everything compiles fine, but now this isn't portable. How can I simply reference the output of the command?

Update: Tried Ken Bloom's suggestion, but it won't compile. The actual generated compiler commands are

```
# How it should be, at least on my machine
g++ -o QOpenCVTest main.o qopencvtest.o moc_qopencvtest.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lml -lcvaux -lhighgui -lcv -lcxcore -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread

# with CONFIG and PKGCONFIG
g++ -o QOpenCVTest main.o qopencvtest.o moc_qopencvtest.o -L/usr/lib -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
```

Comment: What version of qt and qmake do you have ? Ken's suggestions should work but im not sure at which version of qt those where added. Also, could you post your full pro file as there could also be bugs that cause issues such that you see.

Answer (score 44):

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv
```

(I got this answer from http://beaufour.dk/blog/2008/02/using-pkgconfig.html)

Comment: I think this is on the right lines but it doesn't quite work. I'll update the question.

Comment: Maybe the site I got it from was wrong. I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: It should work  just fine on 4.6 qt atleast (where i've tested and still using this). Only "gotcha" is that, if this opencv library is installed *after* qmake has created makefile once (and make file still exists), running make or even qmake itself doesn't make things magically work. So, make distclean && qmake and new makefile should be created with proper libs for compilation.

Comment: @rasjani: Thanks. A lot of the time, I'm just good at googling. Thanks for filling in the details.

Comment: If got `opencv development package not found` @SteveEng's answer solved it!

Comment: if it doesn't work, try adding `QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config`

Answer (score 10):

Ken's answer worked great.  I just had to remove the spaces on either side of the += first.

```
CONFIG+=link_pkgconfig PKGCONFIG+=opencv
```

Comment: For a mac with opencv installed via macports use : LIBS+=/opt/local/lib/libcxcore.dylib LIBS+=/opt/local/lib/libcvaux.dylib LIBS+=/opt/local/lib/libcv.dylib LIBS+=/opt/local/lib/libhighgui.dylib LIBS+=/opt/local/lib/libml.dylib

Answer (score 6):

In the newer version of Qt, this needs to be done to avoid a package not found error:

```
QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += protobuf #or whatever package here
```

Also had to do this for Mac:

```
mac {
  PKG_CONFIG = /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works!!  Is it better move QT_CONFIG, CONFIG, PKGCONFIG into mac { } section for cross compilation ?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this in your qmake file should do

```
LIBS += `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Edit: Hmm, Ken Bloom's answer might be more portable, but erhm not documented?

Comment: Calling bare pkg-config breaks cross compilation. Please avoid calling pkg-config directly.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following lines to your .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LIBS += `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Comment: Calling bare pkg-config breaks cross compilation. Please avoid calling pkg-config directly.