# DSO missing from command line with QMake

Tags: qt, build, qmake

I'm trying to build my Qt app using libcamera on Raspberry Pi, but the qt project won't build, instead showing error: DSO missing from command line.
I have build libcamera from source (it's a .so lib), and included it in my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../libcamera/include
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../libcamera/build/src/libcamera -lcamera
```

I also tried this, with the same result:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/libcamera
LIBS += -lcamera
```

And the exact error:

```
error: /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcamera-base.so.0.0.4: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

I'm pretty sure I'm including it wrong, but I have no idea how to include it the way for it to finally work. How do I include this correctly?

Edit: LibCamera is installed correctly, as [this example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_OVpjTzcUJxYa72u4I5iHZQdKOVIKm86/view?usp=sharing) from [here](https://forum.arducam.com/t/how-to-use-code-to-access-libcamera-c-python/2028) runs normally. Also other Qt apps run, this one does not.

As for includes - $PWD is actually /home/pi/app and in /home/pi/libcamera I have built libcamera from source.

But /usr/local/include/libcamera does contain header files, and /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu does contain libcamera-base.so.

Build command with full output:

```bash
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt/6.2.4-armv8/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/Qt/6.2.4-armv8/lib
 -o app LibCamera.o main.o mainwindow.o qrc_resource.o moc_mainwindow.o   `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` -lpigpiod_if2
 -lrt -ldl -lpython3.9 -lcamera /opt/Qt/6.2.4-armv8/lib/libQt6Charts.so -pthread
 /opt/Qt/6.2.4-armv8/lib/libQt6OpenGLWidgets.so /opt/Qt/6.2.4-armv8/lib/libQt6Widgets.so /opt/Qt/6.2.4-armv8/lib/libQt6OpenGL.so 
/opt/Qt/6.2.4-armv8/lib/libQt6Gui.so -lEGL /opt/Qt/6.2.4-armv8/lib/libQt6Core.so -lpthread -lGLESv2   

/usr/bin/ld: LibCamera.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN9libcamera8UniqueFD5resetEi'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcamera-base.so.0.0.4: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:285: app] Error 1
```

And part of my .pro file (skipping sources, headers and resources):

```
QT       += core gui charts
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
CONFIG += c++14
QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/opencv4
LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
LIBS+= -lpigpiod_if2 -lrt -ldl
CONFIG += no_keywords
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/python3.9
LIBS += -lpython3.9
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/libcamera/libcamera
LIBS += -lcamera
```

`pkg-config libcamera --cflags` shows `-I/usr/local/include/libcamera` and `pkg-config libcamera --libs` shows `-L/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -lcamera -lcamera-base`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Your `INCLUDEPATH` values seem inconsistent. Did you install `libcamera` into `/usr/local`? Didyou check that the header and library files can be found in the specified directories? What directory is `$PWD`? Show your directory structure, the full `.pro` file and the build command with full output. I would expect error messages mentioning the missing symbol(s). You probably did not specify all required libraries, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/19901934/10622916

Comment: @Bodo I edited, including (hopefully) everything you mentioned.

Comment: Does it work if you add `-lcamera-base` to `LIBS`? If not: Can you check which library provides the symbol `_ZN9libcamera8UniqueFD5resetEi`? `libcamera-base`?

Comment: Yup, adding -lcamera-base fixed this! Thanks, add it as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: The correct way to get the compiler and linker arguments might be `pkg-config`. Please show the output of `pkg-config libcamera --cflags` and `pkg-config libcamera --libs`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3517694/10622916

Comment: `pkg-config libcamera --cflags` shows `-I/usr/local/include/libcamera` and `pkg-config libcamera --libs` shows `-L/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -lcamera -lcamera-base`.

Comment: Please add all requested information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to get the compiler and linker arguments seems to be `pkg-config`.

Referring to the answers to [Linking libraries to a QT project using pkg-config output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3517694/10622916) you should use

```
QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += libcamera
```

and remove the manual specification of `INCLUDEPATH` and `LIBS`.

According to different answers, the first line `QT_CONFIG ...` may or may not be necessary.

I did not test the proposed solution.